# TypeScript function return type based on argument type

Tags: typescript

I have two different interfaces: `A` and `B`, which has 1 common property. I also have 2 arrays which consist of items typed with one of this interfaces. I want to have a function which maps them to change this common property and it's return type should be the same as type of the argument (it's either `A[]` or `B[]`).

The example ([TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnKhARwFdh8ATAMWAgBsyAuZAZzClAHMBuHZAewAcwwXiDg0qtBs1YduAXyxZQkWIhQAhTD3zFSEStTqMWbEFywKsEAB79eUMMgQiWyOGTIB5QcNE0AInBgcMgAvMgAFDw0wCyMqADaALrIAD7I6slYAJRhAHzRsWAAdAC2cPwRMSwAkpCl+Vq4uNVgdRClxTok5BJ0YcgARCAQAO7IAG5iRBCDPLj4YERQIMit7aXcuHLZis4grq3xyQMJ2AuEPfp9UgDk9sDsoGKT0xC3ADQ8AkIiYjeMe5sJ5+V40Ga3CxJRQ0CCOCAgNgIAAW+gAMkVUMcUuF3F4fH8AkE4FUirtYfDEcAUeiiupGJkcW4PN5fn5AsFSSxdlh9kxeLDijReOwIgikaiyBiWKhdnyBRAhSKxVSaVK6dkgA)):

```ts
interface A {
  requiredField: string;
  optionalField: string;
}

interface B {
  requiredField: string;
}

export const addOptionalData = (
  list: A[] | B[]
) =>
  list.map(listItem => {
    listItem.requiredField = 'new value'
    return listItem;
  })

const list: A[] = [{
  requiredField: 'original value',
  optionalField: 'original value'
}]

let enrichedListA: A[] = addOptionalData(list) // <-- I have a TS-error here
let enrichedListB: B[] = addOptionalData(list)
```

But here I have a problem with TypeScript, which gives me the following error on `enrichedListA` variable:

> Type '(A | B)[]' is not assignable to type 'A[]'.
> Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type 'A'.
> Property 'optionalField' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'A'.

Understanding that I need to use Generics and conditional types, I tried the following approach, but I don't completely understand how it works so it has it's own errors ([TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnKhARwFdh8ATAMWAgBsyAuZAZzClAHMBuHZAewAcwwXiDg0qtBs1YduAXyxZQkWIhQAhTD3zFSEStTqMWbEFywKsYAJ78UAeQBGAKwgIwAFVsQAPB4B8yAC8yDy4HsgQAB6QIGRMaMgA-In0YcgR0bHxyJopmmm4uCAQAG7Q3FjR-LxQYMgIIizIcGRk9oLCojQAInBgcMHIfpExEHEJ6AA+uf4AFDw0wCyMHlgAlIxOru5edn6BQf6Ly2AAdAC2cPxzSywAkpAXwYHYRch3YI8QF2c6JOQJHQhgAiEoAd2QpTERAgIPS+DARCgIA+p2+F24uDk60UjRAzU+jFQAG0ALpDElvPCEAH6IFSADktWA7FAYihMIgjIANDwBEIRGIGYxmWw2d1OTRYYyLGTFDQIPVxmwEAALfQAGVOqGJ5KGrXanSFvX6cFup1xiuVIFVGrI2pY6kY6n1IUNHUF3T6AwtLHWQA)):

```ts
interface A {
  requiredField: string;
  optionalField: string;
}

interface B {
  requiredField: string;
}

type ObjectType<T> = 
    T extends A ? A :
    T extends B ? B :
    never;

export const addOptionalData = <T extends A | B>(
  list: T
): ObjectType<T> =>
  list.map(listItem => { // I have an error here: "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'A | B'"
    listItem.requiredField = 'new value'
    return listItem;
  })

const list: A[] = [{
  requiredField: 'original value',
  optionalField: 'original value'
}]

let enrichedListA: A[] = addOptionalData(list) // Errors here
let enrichedListB: B[] = addOptionalData(list) // and here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create on parent interface `Parent` and implement the generic function, what will handle it.
Try this:

```
interface Parent {
  requiredField: string;
}

interface A extends Parent {
  optionalField: string;
}

interface B extends Parent {}

export const addOptionalData = <T extends Parent>(
  list: T[]
) =>
  list.map(listItem => {
    listItem.requiredField = "new value"
    return listItem;
  })

const list: A[] = [{
  requiredField: 'original value',
  optionalField: 'original value'
}]

let enrichedListA: A[] = addOptionalData(list)
let enrichedListB: B[] = addOptionalData(list)

console.log(enrichedListA)
console.log(enrichedListB)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to accomplish what you are after. The best approach really depends on the actual data you are trying to model.

### 1. Make `optionalField` optional.

This would be for data that any of these objects could have but isn't required. As an example, if `A` and `B` represent cars, the `optionalField` could be intended to represent the previous owner, which may not exist for cars with one owner.

```js
interface A {
  requiredField: string;
  optionalField?: string; // optional
}

// in this case you may not need interface B at all
interface B {
  requiredField: string;

export const addOptionalData = (
  list: A[] | B[]
) =>
  list.map(listItem => {
    listItem.requiredField = 'new value'
    return listItem;
  })
}
```

### 2. Have interface `A` inherit from interface `B`.

This would be best if your interface `A` is a more detailed version of `B`. For example, `B` is a vehicle and `A` is truck with a property for `bedLength`. Here is what that would look like using generics:

```js
interface A extends B {
  requiredField: string;
  optionalField: string;
}

interface B {
  requiredField: string;
}

export const addOptionalData = <T extends B>(
  list:T[]
) =>
  list.map(listItem => {
    listItem.requiredField = "new value"
    return listItem;
  })
```

### 3. Have both `A` and `B` interfaces inherit a `Parent` interface.

This would be best if the data `A` and `B` are sub-types of some same parent type. For example `A` is a truck, and `B` is a car, both of which are types of `Parent` vehicles:

```js
interface Parent {
  requiredField: string;
}

interface A extends Parent {
  optionalField: string;
}

interface B extends Parent {}

export const addOptionalData = <T extends Parent>(
  list: T[]
) =>
  list.map(listItem => {
    listItem.requiredField = "new value"
    return listItem;
  })
```

Comment: No, in real world this field has some data which is displayed on the website, so it's not really optional, it just doesn't exist in **interface B** (in case of **interface B** I don't need this data)

Comment: In that case, mardukevich's answer is the way to go

Comment: @Nicoffee I updated my answer with a third option. As shown, you don't necessarily need the base interface. Depending on what your app's use case is, you could really go either way. It really depends on what you're trying to model.